# Localization using <a> element or button instead of <select>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a localiztion routine for my website for two languages using a dropdown select element to choose the language which is working fine. I would like to use an a tag or button instead of an dropdown select element. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to pass the culture parameter to the Action Method to set the culture cookie which is done using the name tag helper for select element. What would be the best approach to use an a tag or button to set the language. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        private readonly IHtmlLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHtmlLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _localizer = localizer;
        }
       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Home"] = _localizer["Home"];
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CultureManagement(string culture, string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(30) });

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
 }
```

**Using Select Dropdown**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RequestLocalizationOptions> locOptions

@{
    
    var culture = Context.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureList = locOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures!.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Name, Text = localizer.GetString(x.Name) }).ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
}
```

```
<div>
    <form asp-action="CultureManagement" asp-controller="Home" method="post" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">
        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        <select id="DropDownList" class="selectLang" name="culture" asp-for="@culture!.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureList" onchange="this.form.submit();"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Using Button or a element**

```
<div>
    <form id="cultureform" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CultureManagement" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" method="post" >
        @if (culture!.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name == "en-US")
        {
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" name="culture" asp-for="@culture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" onclick="this.form.submit();">Fr</button>
        }
        else
        {
           
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" name="culture" asp-for="@culture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" onclick="this.form.submit();">En</button>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you set it by the `dropdown` value? Or you didn't able to pass it yet?

Comment: As I stated in my thread the select dropdown works fine. I'm just not able to pass the culture name to an <a> element or button

Answer (score 0):

Why using `post` request to set the culture? just make it `get` and use `<a>` or `<button>`.

```cs
[Route("set-culture-cookie")]
public IActionResult SetCultureCookie(string cltr, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cltr)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Using `<a>`:

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("SetCultureCookie", "Home", new { area="", cltr="EN", returnUrl=returnUrl, culture=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name })">EN</a>
```

See [sample project](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer.Samples/tree/master/MvcLocalizationSample/MvcLocalizationSample)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion into what I have already. Is your suggestion based on Razor Pages? My code I displayed is based on MVC. How does your anchor tag pass the parameters?. The anchor tag is non clickable unless I add a bootstrap btn class